# Swift - Convert String to html?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to achieve what the WordPress app does with the rich text editor. Here are a few images and the link to github repo.

[WordPress-Editor-iOS](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Editor-iOS)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

As you can see from those example and from what I understand is:

That is a normal UITextView where the users types normal/attributedString text and when you tap the button in the top right hand corner of the keyboard it converts the text/attributedString to html??

Not sure if that is correct or not... I have found ways to convert Normal text to html in some other post here on SO, but the result is not the same as the one in that example.

Also when Adding an image to that textView of the Wp-app the image get's uploaded to the server and the in the textView is the link for that image.

I know how to add images to UITextView and upload them but not how to change the "src" name or whatever to the link for the image...

If anyone can help me or give me a quick explanation of how they do this? or how I should approach it I would appreciate it alot!

Thanks alot for your time!

Comment: As I read your question, isn't it just the matter of using an NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute option with NSAttributedString?

Comment: @ElTomato Well yes and no, but I have been working on this over night and I have figure a way out (I think) but my only problem is adding url to the image added to the textView. I have just created a new question..!